# How to set text of Text element in StimulSoft via code?

Tags: if-statement, stimulsoft

I try to set text of Text element in my stimulsoft report via code.I use this code in TextEditor windows into Expression tab.but don't work .I try to use this code into **BeforPrintElement**  and **AfterPrintElement** events but in this case don't print any things.
How to fix this?

```
    {if(ProcGetReportTRAINPDF.Fk_sellerCode=="8006")
      {
    AgencyCommission.value=  ((int.Parse(ProcGetReportTRAINPDF.Formula10)*2)/100).Tostring();
      }
if(ProcGetReportTRAINPDF.Fk_sellerCode=="8025")
      {
    AgencyCommission.value=  ((int.Parse(ProcGetReportTRAINPDF.Formula10)*1.8)/100).Tostring();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Value of the text component is compiled as a method, so it's impossible to change text this way.
You should use the GetValue event of the text component.